# Canvas - FabricJS - Separate stroke from text edge

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to use FabricJS and Canvas to create a text with stroke on it.

I am able to add stroke to text but i want to separate the text from the stroke, like put a margin on the text and then draw the stroke on the outside of the margin.

I have searched and search and cant find anything.

Any advice?

im wondering if there isnt a way to do this with current libraries, is there a way that i can tap into the scripting that creates the and set the start point +x and +y and do that for the whole time it is drawing around the text.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myc');

var text = new fabric.Text('Test', {
    left: 25,
    top: 25,
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: '#fff',
    fontSize: 75,
    strokeOffset: 5   <--- i need something like this
});
canvas.add(text);

<canvas id="myc"></canvas>
```

The result would look something like this...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really separate the stroke from the fill.
What you can do is this:

1) Modify the text render function of fabricjs
invert the stroke and fill order.

2) modify the text stroke function to stroke 2 times:
2a) stroke with a strokeWidth of strokeWidth + strokeOffset with color "red"
2b) stroke with a strokeWidth of strokeOffset with backgroundColor ( not sure if you can use transparent to overwrite it)

3) filling with color will make that effect.

Note:
Maybe using globalCompositeOperation in XOR mode, you can even make it transparent.

Comment: Thanks, Just modified the renderText() function and it worked for me. Great Help

Comment: Could you show us how you did it? Perhaps a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myc');

var text = new fabric.Text('Test', {
    left: 25,
    top: 25,
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: '#fff',
    fontSize: 75,
    strokeOffset: 5  // <--- i need something like this
});
canvas.add(text);
```

```html
<canvas id="myc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello, please edit your answer to reflect proper formatting, it helps keep our community answers more readable.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)